# Proper structure for using individual SQLite files as storage

Tags: android, database, file, sqlite, database-design

I'm building an Android app where the user can create, open, or save data that is stored in SQLite files. **Each individual "session" of data is stored in a separate database file.**

For example, a user creates a document for their recipe, saves it as recipe.sqlite, and then opens and loads otherdocument.sqlite.

I want users to be able to make changes to their documents without saving them permanently. Thus, these changes would be held in a **temporary SQLite database** before being copied over to the original one.

**What is the best way to structure this functionality?**

Here's what I'm thinking:

1. When a user opens some saved SQLite database, we copy/overwrite it over the app's internal SQLite database, which is the only one that is queried by the app. This database lives in the app's folder.
2. The user makes changes to their document and those changes are reflected in the app's internal SQLite database.
3. When the user decides to save to a certain filename, we make a copy of the internal SQLite database as the resulting one.

This approach addresses the need for a temporary SQLite database, but it suffers because it uses twice the space (problematic for large documents) and I/O procedures take time.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It strikes me as an odd choice to create one database per document in your application instead of using one database that holds the data for many documents. Is there a reason for designing the app this way?

To allow users to make temporary changes, you could use transactions and not commit them until the user wants to make the changes permanent.

Comment: The reasoning behind that choice is to allow documents to be transferred between Android devices/viewed on any device. Does SQLite support transactions? I guess transactions could be stored in memory, but if the app is closed or crashes, they would be lost.

Comment: SQLite does support transactions, but I believe you are correct that they would be lost if the app closes or crashes.  You might be able to add a column to your database table to indicate that data in a row is temporary or permanent as another solution.  Regarding transfer between devices, you could export/import your data using a format like XML or JSON.